# Trigger that updates a column on the row where I clicked update

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, database-trigger

So I have this table:

```
ID Name IsDeleted
1  test True
2  test2 False
```

I currently have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_test_IsDeleted]
ON [dbo].[test]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE dbo.test
    SET IsDeleted = 1
    WHERE ID = 1;
END
```

When I click the delete button on a row in my index view, I need this trigger to launch and set IsDeleted to 1 (or True) on that exact row. However, doing it with the above trigger will obviously delete only the row source where ID = 1. And if I leave out the WHERE statement, it sets IsDeleted for all rows to true.

I need my trigger to dynamically determine where "delete" is being pressed and only delete that row.

I know that in MySQL, you can accomplish this by using the following in a delete trigger:

```
SET new.IsDeleted = 1
```

Is there a way to get the same effect as "new." in SQL Server triggers?

And since we're on the topic, I want to achieve the same thing, but with altering the current code in the controller. Here is what it looks like now:

```
//POST - Delete
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        var test = await _db.Test.FindAsync(id);

        if (test== null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        _db.Test.Remove(test);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

This code will achieve an ordinary delete operation on the database. I want to alter it to set "IsDeleted" to 1 instead of deleting the record.

Comment: Why not just do the `UPDATE` command from your code instead of issuing a `DELETE` and assuming the Trigger will always be enabled? That’s a dangerous assumption because Triggers are often disabled during maintenance operations and you’ll have fun recovering data if someone forgets to re-enable the Trigger.

Comment: If necessary to use a trigger please check the docs on the [inserted and deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) pseudo-tables.

Comment: @Dai, I think they want to mark the deleted record instead of actual deleting even if someone deletes the row from outside of application. However your point is also valid.

Comment: @Dai Yeah, I've been thinking about that since posting the question, and I think it would be better (from a debugging standpoint) to just alter the delete method on the controller in my code. It's just that I'm currently more used to triggers, so my question is based in my comfort zone. Also, I want to enforce my business logic in my database to protect it in case a new front-end is built on it. If I could, I might just enforce it on the trigger as well as the controller, but that could lead to conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a flag instead of delete (which some people call it `SOFT DELETE`), you should update your trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_test_IsDeleted]
ON [dbo].[test]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE dbo.test
    SET deleted.IsDeleted = 1
    WHERE ID = deleted.ID; --<-- This is the key point
END
```

Comment: Does that work without explicitly joining on `deleted`?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to join while you have the deleted ID. Just be aware that this only work on single delete which is your case. If you want to support bulk delete ypu need see changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the 'deleted' virtual table, and perform the update accordingly.  EG:

```
create table test(id int primary key, IsDeleted bit default 0)
go
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_test_IsDeleted]
ON [dbo].[test]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE dbo.test
    SET IsDeleted = 1
    WHERE ID in (select id from deleted); 
END
go 

insert into test(id, IsDeleted) values (1,0),(2,0),(3,0)

delete from test where id = 2

select * from test
```

outputs

```
id          IsDeleted
----------- ---------
1           0
2           1
3           0

(3 rows affected)
```